# Recover the order of records

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a table that in addition to some data has the `n` column storing the index of the next record.  For example,

```
q)show t:([]x:"cbad";n:3 0 1 4)
x n
---
c 3
b 0
a 1
d 4
```

I am looking for a method to recover the order of the records from this information.  In the example above the correct order is `abcd` and the `n` column tells us that `c` is followed by `d`, `b` is followed by `c`, `a` is followed by `b`, and `d` is the last record (note the out of range index in the `n` column).

```
q)select x,next_x:x n from t
x next_x
--------
c d
b c
a b
d
```

The last record always comes last (at the right place) and the algorithm may assume this.

[EDIT]

Here is a one-liner that I came up with:

```
q)t exec n\[-1+count n;]first where @[(1+count n)#1b;n;:;0b] from t
x n
---
a 1
b 0
c 3
d 4
```

Answer (score 1):

With your assumptions you can do something like:

```
t exec -2_n\[first i except n] from t
```

speeds your example up by about 30%, and a bit more elegant I think :-)

Matt

Comment: If you haven't seen it before you might also find Stevan Apter's article in vector on treetables pretty interesting (http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10500340)  Your problem made me think of it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Very interesting.  Unfortunately, when I tried your solution on a larger test case I got a `'loop` error.

Comment: How large is the test case/dataset you are using?

Comment: `'loop` is a pretty strange error to see for this.  It indicates you have a dependency cycle if you're using views like `a::a`.  Any chance your full table has a column called `loop` or something similar?  that's the only other thing I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

Someone in office came up with a simplification of your solution:

```
t exec n\[-1+count i;first i except n]from t
```

I have a one liner solution of my own, it is not quicker than the one above but it makes use of a dictionary defining what the next char is to get the right order:

```
{a:-1_r\[key[r]except value r:x[`x]!x[`x]x`n];x a?/:x`x}t
x n
---
a 1
b 0
c 3
d 4
```

Comment: I simplified my solution somewhat and it is now about 10% faster than yours on a realistic test case.